# Select tag option in VBA

Tags: html, vba

Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")

```
For Each opt In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("option")
    If opt.innerText = "1000" Then
        Debug.Print "found it"
        opt.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt
```

I want it to appear like this:

[image]

That's how it appears:

[image]

Comment: Please update to explain the problem and include the relevant html.

Comment: HTML code has already been included, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is the HTML code

```
 <select size="1" name="ocorrencias_listar_length" aria-controls="ocorrencias_listar">

<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="25" selected="selected">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="250">250</option>
<option value="500">500</option>
<option value="1000">1000</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The html code should go via [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69815845/edit) to your original question above. Also, please make clear what the problem is and order the text and code in a way that is sequential.